# Averaging data over Latitude and Longitude using R

Tags: r

I have data based on latitude and longitude values which i would like to aggregate into a smaller subset following a coarser resolution of latitude and longitude.

Data set:

```
Latitude Longitude  Total.MB
 23.0     -180       57.901667
 23.5     -180       11.058667
 24.0     -180        1.176667
 24.5     -180       12.726500
 25.0     -180        9.101500
 29.5     -180       46.250668
```

Would like to define latitude and longitude "grid" as 5deg-by-5deg squares and get the sum of Total.MB over each square.
This is what the new data frame would look like:

```
Latitude Longitude  Total.MB
 20.0     -180       100.041667
 25.0     -180        15.058667
 30.0     -180        16.176667
 20.0     -175       128.726500
 25.0     -175       498.101500
 30.0     -175       146.250668
```

I tried understanding the aggregate function and plyr library functions, but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use the `cut` function with 5-deg intervals as breaks to segment your latitude and longitude into a grid: `cut(df$Latitude, breaks = seq(from=0, to=90, by=5))` (analogous for Longitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, here is one possible solution:

```
df<-data.frame(Lattitude=c(23, 23.5, 24, 24.5,25,29.5), 
               Longitude=c(-180, -180, -180, -175, -175, -175), 
               Total.MB=c(57.9, 11.1, 1.18, 12.7, 9.1, 46.3))
ddply(df, ~(round(Lattitude / 5)*5)+(round(Longitude / 5)*5), 
          summarize, Total.MB=sum(Total.MB))
```

Comment: thank you Doctor Dan. That was exactly what I was looking for